# SQL SELECT and COUNT of second table

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, left-join

Having 2 tables:

```
users
==========
id
name

notes
=========
id
user_id
note
```

Users *can* have multiple notes.

I would like to do a SQL query that gets all users with all their fields but also the amount of notes. Further I would like the result to be ordered by the amount of notes (desc)

I wrote this, but I want to know if it's is the correct/fastest way to solve this:

```
SELECT u.*, count(n.id) as amountnotes FROM users AS u 
LEFT JOIN notes AS n ON u.id=n.user_id
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY amountnotes DESC
```

`EXPLAIN` gives me 2 results. "Using temporary; Using filesort" on users and "Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop)" on notes

Any help appreciated, thanks. If suggesting a different approach please explain why so I can understand.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your query!

Comment: what does `explain your query` says ?

Comment: share that explain result to the question, since doing join on non indexed field and not same datatype will make it slow in addition group by and order by also depends on how indexes are done. For small set of data all looks good but when you have large data set then these small small things makes a lot of difference in the query time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `COUNT` is all you want, you can do it with a subquery rather than a join, like this:

```
SELECT u.*
,      (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM notes WHERE notes.user_id=u.id) as amountnotes
FROM users u
ORDER BY amountnotes DESC
```

If you do it the `JOIN` way, your `GROUP BY` *should* list all columns of the `user` (although MySql is one of the RDBMS systems that does not require this, porting such SQL to databases of other vendors becomes problematic).

Comment: But is this faster/better, and why?

Comment: @Sanne On any mature RDBMS system this should not be faster than `group by`. However, this is more portable than grouping by `u.id` alone, because other RDBMSs require all fields of `u` to be included in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: @Sanne: In MySQL, it's likely this will be slower for large sets, because of the way MySQL processes it. The correlated subquery in the SELECT list is run for every row returned by the outer query. BUT, this form does work in other databases.

Comment: Thanks both for explanation. I want to give you both points but that's not allowed.

Answer (score 2):

Your query will return the resultset you specified, assuming that `id` is UNIQUE (or PRIMARY) KEY in `users` table.  Your query looks fine for MySQL.

Best practice is to list out the expressions you want returned, rather than using the `*`; but what you have is valid.

Note that this query will work in MySQL, but other databases will throw an error, because there are non-aggregates in the SELECT list that are not included in the GROUP BY.

(Your query isn't the only way to get the specified resultset, there are several alternatives).